# how to log out from google login on my blazor web server app?

Tags: google-oauth, blazor-server-side

I'm adding google login to my webapp (blazor server). I'm using this piece of code for the login:

At program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Cookies")
    .AddCookie(opt =>
    {
        opt.Cookie.Name = "TrySingOutGoogleAuth";
        opt.LoginPath = "/auth/google-login";
    })
    .AddGoogle(opt =>
    {
        opt.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Google:Id"] ?? "Not Found";
        opt.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Google:Secret"] ?? "Google secret not found";
        opt.Scope.Add("profile");
        opt.Events.OnCreatingTicket = context =>
        {
            string picuri = context.User.GetProperty("picture").GetString() ?? "No picuri found";
            context.Identity?.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", picuri));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

And added a controller for the login:

```
[HttpGet("google-login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Google()
{
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/"
    };
    return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

A piece of code I honestly don't understand. After doing other settings in the program.cs and some stuff it works. Question now is: How do I do something for the logout? I cannot find help for that on the internet :(
I'd like to keep using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication things, and not mix with some javascript. Is that possible?

I noticed that just deleting the cookie seams to log me out, but I'm not sure if that's a good practice at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Route("logout")]
    public IActionResult Logout() {
        return SignOut(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

Comment: InvalidOperationException: The authentication handler registered for scheme 'Google' is 'GoogleHandler' which cannot be used for SignOutAsync. The registered sign-out schemes are: Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Juding from your codes,

```
.AddCookie(opt =>
    {
        opt.Cookie.Name = "TrySingOutGoogleAuth";
        opt.LoginPath = "/auth/google-login";
    })
```

.....

```
[HttpGet("google-login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Google()
{
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/"
    };
    return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

Your default authentication scheme should be cookie ,and after you login with your google account successfully,it would store the claims in cookie

So you should  call `HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookie");`

Comment: Here's a  sample similar with your issue and might help:https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/19